# Tablename too long in PROC COMPARE

Tags: sas

I am trying to compare two tables using SAS code in PROC COMPARE.

The Table names are too long- they pass the 32 character limit. 
I cannot re-name the files in the Source Database.

Is there anyway to get around this? I tried assigning to a variable, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a view with a valid sas name (ie length name <= 32) and then use the view in proc compare.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou francesco. I started creating the views, but it was taking a long time as i had to create the source table as views as well. I decided to output the results to a text file and 'Compare' using Notepad ++. Great pluggin! :)) works wonders :)